# Vaadin Combo-Box: Using value property to pass the index of a selected item

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin-elements

I am trying to discern the index # of the pattern selected in the Combo-box. I need to pass this index value in order for another function to read from a file at the correct location. Essentially, selecting the a pattern in the combobox will let me do a lookup for specifications associated with the selected pattern based on the index. To the best of my knowledge the Vaadin Combobox does not have an index associated with the combobox items, but you are able to pass a different value than the displayed label: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box-basic.html (**see: Using Objects as Items**). This is solution I am trying to implement, however it gets tricky because I am dynamically populating the combobox items from a JSON file.

**The code to dynamically populate the items:**

```
paver = document.querySelector('#paver');
    //alert('script executed');
    patterns = [];
    familyind=y;


    $.getJSON('menu.json').done(function(data){
        //alert('getJSON request succeeded!');

        family = (data.gui[x].family[y].display);

         for(ind = 0; ind < data.gui[x].family[y].pattern.length; ind++){

            var patternLbl = data.gui[x].family[y].pattern[ind].name;
            var patternObj = '{ pattern: { label: "' + patternLbl + '", value: ' + ind + ' } }';

            patterns[ind] = patternObj;
        }
        document.getElementById("cb1").items=patterns;

         })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            { 
                alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); 
            })
        .always(function() { }};
```

**HTML for the ComboBox**

```
<div id="patternSelect">
            <template is="dom-bind" id="paver">
              <div class="fieldset">
               class="patterns" items="[[patterns]]" item-label-path="pattern.label" item-value-path="pattern.value"></vaadin-combo-box>
              </div>
            </template>
        </div>
```

The output I get when I try to execute this is that the entire constructed string gets assembled into my selection choices. Theoretically, this should not have happened because the item-value-path and item-label-path were specified when declaring the combobox.
**Screenshot of Output**
[image: Broken Labels]

**It says:**  { pattern: { label: "A-3 Piece Random", value: 0 } }

**WORKING TOWARDS A SOLUTION SECTION:**

___________(April 27, 7:00pm)___________

Suggested solution to use,

```
var patternObj = { pattern: { label: patternLbl, value: ind } };
```

works fine in displaying labels:
[image: Working labels]

However, I am using a trigger to detect when the value in the combo-box is changed and return the new value. Here is the code for the trigger:

```
// select template
var paver = document.querySelector('#paver');

// define the ready function callback
paver.ready = function () {
    // use the async method to make sure you can access parent/siblings
    this.async(function() {
    // access sibling or parent elements here
    var combobox = document.querySelector('#cb1')

    combobox.addEventListener('value-changed', function(event) {

    // FOR REFERENCE LOG ERRORS, THIS COMMENT IS ON HTML:215    
       console.log(event.detail.value);
       patval = event.detail.value;
       console.log(patval)

        // Do stuff with fetched value


        });
    });
};
```

I have made the suggested change to using a 'value-changed' trigger. It works very well with two slight issues. First, it returns each of the console log calls twice (not sure why twice). Second, when I select the first combo-box item it returns my values but does not set the label as selected. This is not an issue with the other combo-box items, but the first item needs to be selected twice to have the label set. Please watch this short video for a demonstration: https://youtu.be/yIFc9SiSOUM. This graphical glitch would confuse the user as they would think they did not select a pattern when they know they had. Looking for a solution to make sure the label is set when the first item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a currently a String to `patternObj` while you should be setting an Object.

Try using either `var patternObj = JSON.parse('{ pattern: { label: "' + patternLbl + '", value: ' + ind + ' } }';` or even simpler: 
`var patternObj = { pattern: { label: patternLbl, value: ind } };`

Also, I would recommend initializing the `patterns = []` inside the `done` callback to make sure you're not leaving any old items in the `patterns` when the data changes.

Comment: I tried this solution. The first version returns a JSON error: unexpected token 'p'. However, the 'even simpler' version works to provide me with a label in the pattern selection combo-box, but does not successfully set a value. I have edited my initial question to include the trigger I will be using to gather the value. The trigger is return a value [object Object].

Comment: Right, the selectedItem contains the item object, so you need to either log `event.detail.value.pattern.value`, or use the `value` property instead which holds the string value of the selected item. So, you can listen to `value-changed` event instead. See https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box-value.html for more details.

Comment: Returning the `...value.pattern.value` and `...value.pattern.label` works to return the requested values to a log, but is unable to be read into a variable. To demonstrate, I have updated the trigger above and also added a screenshot of the console with returned errors.

Comment: selectedItem will change to null after deselection before the next value is selected so you need null checks. But I strongly recommend in this case listening to 'value-changed' event instead of 'selected-item-changed'

Comment: I have made the suggested change to using a 'value-changed' trigger. It works very well with two slight issues. Please see updated question above.

Comment: Which version are you running? There has been in an issue about the `value-changed` being fired twice:  https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/188 which should be fixed in 1.0.0-rc1

Comment: Not sure what version this would fetch. I assume it would gather the latest, but my import statements are: `<script src="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/latest/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>`
   `<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box.html">`. Do you think this is also related to the graphical bug?

Comment: Right, that uses the master version where this issue is solved. Would you be able to provide a code snippet in jsbin.com or similar so I could try it myself?